How much may be omitted in cases of VP ellipsis involving multiply-embedded clauses?
Dear native English speakers of this beautiful forum
I would like you to entertain the meaning of the sentence below, which has the rather simple form Mary suspected that the fingerprints had in fact not been so-and-so, the only real difference being the fact that the embedded subject, i.e. the fingerprints, contains a long-ass trail of self-embedded relative clauses that we mark here in bold for easiness of reference.

Mary suspected that the fingerprints [that had been secretly reported by cops [to have been deemed by experts [to have been proven by multiple tests [to have been John’s]]]] had in fact not

Now, taking X to stand (by convention) for the long-ass NP in bold, I would like you to take a brief moment to consider which of the examples below provide a possible construal (or a good enough paraphrase, depending on the context) of our original sentence:

(1) Mary suspected that X had in fact not been secretly reported by cops to have been deemed by experts to have been proven by multiple tests to have been John’s
(2) Mary suspected that X had in fact not been deemed by experts to have been proven by multiple tests to have been John’s
(3) Mary suspected that X had in fact not been proven by multiple tests to have been John’s
(4) Mary suspected that X had in fact not been John’s

One last question. Consider now the following sentence, which differs minimally from our first one in having an infinitival verb form in a place where the first had a finite counterpart (had been > to have been).

Mary suspected that the fingerprints [to have been secretly reported by cops [to have been deemed by experts [to have been proven by multiple tests [to have been John’s]]]] had in fact not

Is there any difference in the array of paraphrases admissible? In particular, for those of you that reject (1) in the the former case, do you feel that (1) might be conveyed using the latter case that has the infinitive form instead?

That's an absurdly complicated sentence which would baffle even a native speaker. Any decent writer would unpack it to make the meaning clear. The police had reported the expert opinion, proved by multiple tests, that the fingerprints were John's etc. etc.

The second sentence seems ungrammatical to me; is it real-world?

It is unclear what the bracketed "sentence" means. The limits of what what Mary suspects are unclear.

To quote the late, great John Lawler: 'It might be grammatical, but that's the only good thing you can say about it.' Unwieldiness and unresolved ambiguity, as well as the omission of important information, are contraventions of Gricean maxims and Orwell's Sixth Law.

I don't find that first sentence particularly hard to understand, though even on purely semantic grounds (4) is the most sensible interpretation. No clue what the second one is supposed to mean; it's an odd use of a relative infinitive.

By 'VP…' did you mean 'verb phrase ellipsis' or what, please?
Here, Dear Zoltan, I for one would like you to entertain the differences between the your very different presentations of what Mary might have meant in your first and second interpretations, and your last four uses of 'X' to stand (by your unstated convention) for the long-ass NP in bold.
Unless you aim to create confusion, how could it hurt to put all six instances in similar formats?
